# Invalid character ':' in value part of property on Tomcat 7.0.50 startup

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, tomcat7

We have started getting a weird exception upon tomcat deployment, which prevents the server from starting. The setup was running for months without issues.

- Maven Project
- Eclipse Kepler 4.3.0
- Tomcat 7.0.50 (as Eclipse plugin)

Has anyone had this exception? Any idea on where to look for the problem?

```
javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character ':' in value part of property
    at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(ObjectName.java:618)
    at javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(ObjectName.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.register(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.initInternal(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.initInternal(ContainerBase.java:1084)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.initInternal(StandardContext.java:6462)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should clean tomccat's directory, probably some dependencies floating aroung,[please check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502241/tomcat-fails-to-start-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

Okay that worked, I had to:

- Run "Add and Remove...", "Clean..." on The server
- Maven > Update Project (with clean enabled) on the project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems a properties file has that character as part of a value. You must escape it.
Note that althougt the usual syntax is `key=value`, `key:value` is also [valid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties#Format)

Comment: Checked all *.properties files in project scope, there are no ":" in any of them. Any idea on how to get more specific logs?

Comment: Check the container configuration, it seems that properties file belongs to it rather than to your application (the conf folder has some properties files, for example)

Comment: Hi Pablo, thanks for the reply, we have two different local setups, both show the same behavior but other WebApps deploy on them just fine...

Comment: Are you using JMX? The trace shows that something (a MBean) is trying to be registered and maybe the name is incorrect.