# Jersey 2.2 not getting initialized

Tags: maven-2, tomcat7, jax-rs, restful-architecture, jersey-2.0

Im using Eclipse Kepler and Tomcat 7.0.x. I have created a Maven project with the following specification.

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

But when starting the project.I dont get the logger info that says "Initializing Jersey Application" hence the service isnt working.

I just get the logger info of the Tomcat startup. Hence when i call the sample maven project i get 404. what could be the reason ?

If i try creating a clean Dynamic Web Project I still get the problem in this post and couldnt proceed anywhere with JAX RS 2.0 and Tomcat [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502241/tomcat-fails-to-start-in-eclipse)

Comment: By maven, I suppose you're using the `mvn:archetype` as outlined [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html#new-from-archetype)? In that case, you should have your JAX-RS resource classes in the package you specified in your `mvn:archetype` command, viz., `com.example`. Failing that, you can change an entry your deployment descriptor to point to the package where you have your JAX-RS resources.

Comment: I didnt understand what you explained above but i used the link you mentioned and successfully deployed a Resr JAX RS 2.x application in Tomcat after a long time. I started with Maven project then followed the steps in the website and got the project working. But i wanted to try in a simple Dynamic Web Project. So I took all the jars that got imported because of Maven dependency and put that in the lib of my dynamic Project. My question is had i known these set of jars upfront my struggle would have been less. How to figure out the exact set of jars without Maven.